# How to automatically resize divs to match window size

Tags: html, css, resize

I want to change it so when I resize my window everything including divs are resized. Not just the background. I have just started HTML so I may not be familiar with the more advanced concepts. What can I do to resize the divs in my page to fit the window?

This is my main page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>  
<!-- META -->
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>Keyan Kazemian</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css"        type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styleone.css">
</head>
<body>
<div style="background: rgba(30,26,29,0.7); position: fixed; top:300px; left:440px; height:160px;   width:600px; moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px;">
<h1> Keyan Kazemian </h1>
<p> Hello, my name is Keyan and this is my life. </p>
</div>
<a style="display:block" href="about-me.html"> <div class="links">About Me</div> </a>
<a style="display:block" href="#music.html"> <div class="linktwo"> Music </div> </a>
<a style="display:block" href="#comingsoon"> <div class="linkthree"> Video </div> </a>
<a style="display:block" href="#comingsoon"> <div class="linkfour"> App Development </div> </a>

</body>
</html>
```

This is My style sheet

```
.links { background: rgba(30,26,29,0.7); position: fixed; top:300px; left:1046px; height:160px; width:200px; moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; color:#fcfcf5; font-size: 1.5em; font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 80px;}
.linktwo { background: rgba(30,26,29,0.7); position: fixed; top:300px; left:1252px; height:160px; width:200px; moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; color:#fcfcf5; font-size: 1.5em; font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 160px;}
.linkthree { background: rgba(30,26,29,0.7); position: fixed; top:300px; left:1458px; height:160px; width:200px; moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; color:#fcfcf5; font-size: 1.5em; font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 160px;}
.linkfour { background: rgba(30,26,29,0.7); position: fixed; top:300px; left:1664px; height:160px; width:200px; moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; color:#fcfcf5; font-size: 0.9em; font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 80px;}
a:link {text-align: center; color: #fcfcf5; text-decoration:none; font-size: 2em; font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;} 
a:visited {text-align: center; color: #fcfcf5; text-decoration:none; font-size: 2em; font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;} 
a:hover {text-align: center; color: #fcfcf5; text-decoration:none; font-size: 2em; font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;} 
a:active {text-align: center; color: #fcfcf5; text-decoration:none; font-size: 2em; font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;} 

html { 
    background: url(trop.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
    body {font-size: 100%;}
    h1 {color:#fcfcf5; font-size: 3em; font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive; text-align: center;}
    p {color:#fcfcf5; font-size: 1.5em; font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive; text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called responsive layout, which changes as per the screen resolution. Note that, it is not just sufficient to resize divs, Paragraphs etc. but you need to consider lot of other things like

- Navigation bar
- Images
- Grids etc.

Covering RWD in this post is impossible, but you can find lot of stuff on search engine. Still refer these links available [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-tutorials/), [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIz02qY5BRA) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh653584.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media queries for smaller devices also called responsive design (window resize)
Use this with your main stylesheet. Use smaller font size and margin for DIVs so that it can be viewable on small devices.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  selector {
    //style for smaller devices
  }
}
```

For example media queries for iPads

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  
{ 
/* STYLES GO HERE */
//use width upto 768px
}

//media queries for iPad mini

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
{ 
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}
```

go through this [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for more information on media queries.